# CQ - Check whether the resource object is valid

Tags: aem, jcr, sling

I need to check whether the resource object is valid or not for the below 'resource' object. For example If I pass any url like `getResource("some path which is not available in cq")` in this case I need to restrict it

```
Resource resource= resourceResolver.getResource(/content/rc/test/jcr:content");
Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
String parentPagePath= node.getProperty("someproperty").getValue().getString();
```

Is there any way to do?

Comment: Can you please accept an answer and help close this question ?

Comment: When Using Sightly Answer is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54419352/how-to-check-if-child-component-resource-exist-or-not-using-sightly-in-aem

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you are using `getResource` a null check is sufficient. If you use `resolve`, then you have to use the `!ResourceUtil.isNonExistingResource(resource)`.
On Node level you can check the existence of a property with `hasProperty`.

Answer (score 4):

As Thomas said , `ResourceResolver.getResource()` returns `null` if the path you provide as argument does not exist. A null check on the resource should get your problem solved .

```
Resource resource= resourceResolver.getResource("some path which is not available in cq");
if(resource != null){
Node node = resource.adaptTo(Node.class);
String parentPagePath= node.getProperty("someproperty").getValue().getString();
}
```

**Just a side note :**
Its *mostly* better to play around with a wrapper than to work with a lower level API unless there is a compelling reason to do so.

Hence , I would recommend you to deal with [ValueMap](https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ValueMap.html)(Sling API) to retrieve/set properties of Node rather than dealing with the [Node](http://www.day.com/maven/jsr170/javadocs/jcr-2.0/javax/jcr/Node.html) (JCR API)

```
Resource resource= resourceResolver.getResource("some path which is not available in cq");
    if(resource != null){
    ValueMap mapWithAllTheValues = resource.adaptTo(ValueMap.class);
    String parentPagePath= mapWithAllTheValues.get("someproperty", String.class);
    }
```

Ref : 
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/javadoc/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceResolver.html#getResource(java.lang.String)