# How to check if child component resource exist or not using Sightly in AEM?

Tags: aem, sightly

my component has an embedded image component inside of it, i need to show image only if image component is authored,

**Component Code:**

```
<div class="col-md-4">
<sly data-sly-resource="${'image' @ resourceType='test/components/content/image'}"></sly>
</div>
```

So i need to check resource of embedded image component authored or not

i know we can do this in Java, but how to do this in Sightly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be doable ,using **${resource['image/jcr:primaryType']}**,

here image is child component

```
<sly data-sly-test="${resource['image/jcr:primaryType']}">
<div class="col-xs-5 col-md-4">
<sly data-sly-resource="${'image' @ resourceType='test/components/content/image'}"></sly>
</div>
</sly>
```